# Segfault with vector of pointers to vectors

Tags: c++, stl, vector, segmentation-fault

I have narrowed down the problem to this line:

```
    indg = nets[i]->adjlist[i].size();   // indg is in a method of the Ensemble class
```

Where the above variables are

```
    vector<DDNetwork*> nets;    // this vector is in the Ensemble class

    int indg;

    class DDNetwork
    {
        friend class Ensemble;
        ...
        public: 
            vector< vector<int> > adjlist;  // the adjacency list of the network
        ...
    };
```

I don't understand why `indg = nets[i]->adjlist[i].size();` would cause a segfault, is there something I am missing? Also if you need more information I can add it.

EDIT: <strike>I just realized what was wrong</strike>, I am using the same index for `adjlist` that I am for `nets`, the line

```
    indg = nets[i]->adjlist[i].size();
```

should be:

```
    indg = nets[i]->adjlist[j].size();
```

EDIT: After stepping through the debugger, I noticed that in the constructor of `Ensemble`, `nets.size() = 10` (expected), but when the method `Ensemble::alloc_dev_memory` is called, `nets.size() = 803384` (unexpected), so I think that JaredPar's second suggestion might explain the problem. Here is the code that adds DDNetwork* instances into the nets variable:

```
    Ensemble::Ensemble(int N, float K, int S, bool seedrand, int ltype, int numNets)
    {
        this->N = N;
        this->K = K;
        this->S = S;
        this->ltype = ltype;
        this->numNets = numNets;

        if(seedrand)
            srand(time(0));

        nets.resize(numNets);    // make a vector of pointers to DDNetwork
        for(int i=0; i < numNets; ++i)
            nets[i] = new DDNetwork(N,K,S,seedrand,ltype);

        // pre-compute the S^k for k=0,1,...,Kmax
        Spow[0]=1;                  // S^0 = 1
        int k=1;
        while(k <= Kmax*2) {
            Spow[k] = S*Spow[k-1];  // S^k = S*(S^(k-1))
            ++k;
        }
    }
```

This constructor is called when I instantiate the ensemble variable in my `main` function:

```
    // instantiate ensemble of networks
    Ensemble ens(N, K, S, seed_rand, multiedge, numNets);
    // run_the ensemble one time step
    ens.run_gpu();
```

And after that, `Ensemble::run_gpu` calls `Ensemble::alloc_dev_memory`, then when `nets[i]->adjlist[j].size()` is called, that's when I receive the segmentation fault.

How would the `nets` reference get uninitialized?

Comment: Add the initialization code of the adjlist.

Comment: Perhaps your `i` is out of the bounds of the vector?

Comment: Either `nets[i]` is out of bounds, or `nets[i]->adjlist[i]` is out of bounds.

Comment: right before the line crashing, you can use `assert(i<nets.size()); assert(i<nets[i]->adjlist.size());` to find out if it's one of those two.

Comment: Voting to close as "too localized" as: The OP has solved his problem; they have not submitted it as their own answer; and the problem boiled down to a typo that is unlikely to help with any general problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the source of the segfault by accident, I was doing some crude debugging because GDB didn't have information about my main.cpp file, and in order to print out `nets.size()`, I had to temporarily make `vector<DDNetwork*> nets` public, after doing that, I realized that the program didn't segfault anymore. I thought it might have to do with the `private`/`public` distinction, but when I moved the line

```
public:
    vector<DDNetwork*> nets;
private:
```

to

```
public:
private:
    vector<DDNetwork*> nets;
```

line, the program still didn't segfault, so I tried moving the line `vector<DDNetwork*> nets;` back to where it used to be, all the way below all of the other method and member declarations, just before the closing brace `};`, and the program began to segfault as before. What is it about the location of the line `vector<DDNetwork*> nets;` that was causing the segfault?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is likely one of the following

- The `DDNetwork*` reference in `nets[i]` is uninitialized causing a segfault when you access the members.
- The size of `nets` and each instance of `adjlist` is not kept in sync causing one of the offsets to be invalid

Could you post the code which adds `DDNetwork*` instances into the `nets` variable?

Comment: I figured it out once I read your answer and the comments, I was using the wrong index on `adjlist` and that was causing it to go out of bounds.

Comment: That wasn't the real problem though, it turns out that at the point in the program right before it segfaults, the `nets` vector has the wrong size.

Answer (score 0):

There are two possibilities. Either there isn't a *new* `DDNetwork` at index `nets[i]` or `adjlist[i]` hasn't been created.

To have a square vector of vectors you need to resize them properly:

```
adjlist.resize( MAX );
for (int i = 0; i < MAX; ++i)
  adjlist[i].resize( MAX );
```

...**only** then can you index them. Alternatively you can `push_back` proper values.

Note also that you use the **same** index for the nets array, and the adjlist array, unsure whether that was intended.